# What photography can I use 24-70mm lens?

Tags: lens, nikon, equipment-recommendation

What photography is 24-70mm lens useful for?

Comment: anything that fits in the viewfinder & many things that don't.

Comment: Pretty much whatever you want, you can get away with landscape, portrait and possibly sports depending on other factors. As Tetsujin said, whatever you can fit into the view finder.

Comment: This question is likely to be downvoted and/or closed in short order as you haven't made it clear what actual problem you're trying to solve. Could you try and edit your question to explain *why* you're asking this and what you'd like to learn from the answer?

Answer (score 3):

All of the photographies. Every.Single.One.*

---

*Except super wide and longer telephoto. Macro will be difficult without some additional accessories, and you won't get super open either (I've never seen a 24-70 with an aperture larger than f/2.8). But, really, you can shoot a good deal with that range...just not everything.

Answer (score 2):

### Have you ever heard the phrase, "Getting the cart before the horse?"

That's the way many, if not most, photographers would view your question.

For most of us the process is the reverse: We have a photo, or a series of photos, or a particular style of photos, that we want to take. Then we ask ourselves the question: "What lens will allow me to take such a photo?"

When considering zoom lenses we do tend to ask things such as, "What focal length ranges do the images I most often want to shoot fall within?" or "Will the compromise in image quality versus using multiple prime lenses outweigh the cost savings and/or need to constantly change lenses?" or "Will the higher cost of a premium zoom lens be worth getting near prime quality at the focal lengths included in that lens' range and not having to change lenses all of the time?" But it is still usually in the context of needing a lens to cover specific focal lengths with a specific maximum aperture.

On the other hand, we also tend to divide lens focal lengths into three broad categories: Wide angle, normal, and telephoto. Where the lines are between each category will depend on the format (sensor or film size) of the camera.

For example, a 50mm lens on a large format camera is considered very wide angle because it gives a very wide field of view with 8x10" negatives (the diagonal is about 325mm, so a 50mm lens on an 8x10 camera would give roughly the same field of view as a 7mm lens on a FF/35mm camera). A 50mm lens on a medium format camera is considered wide angle because it gives a wide angle FoV with medium format sizes such as 120 film (the diagonal of a 6x7 negative is 87mm, a 50mm lens is slightly more than half that). A 50mm lens on a FF/35mm camera is considered normal because it is almost the same as the 43.3mm diagonal. A 50mm lens on an APS-C camera is considered mildly telephoto because it is about 1.8X the roughly 27-28mm diagonal of APS-C size sensors. A 50mm lens on a micro four-thirds camera is squarely in telephoto country with a focal length well over twice the 21.6mm diagonal measurement.

### So, for what can a 24-70mm lens be used?

24-70mm lenses are typically used on full frame/35mm cameras. With such cameras they cover the "normal" range of focal lengths: from about half the image format's diagonal measure to a little more than one and a half times the same diagonal. The modern 24-70mm f/2.8 lens is a successor to the older 28-70mm or 28-75mm f/2.8 lenses, which covered from about 2/3 to 5/3 of the 35mm diagonal.

For an APS-C camera, the same range would be covered by about a 15/16-44/45mm focal length. In practice, we see a lot of 17-50mm, 17-55mm, and 18-55mm lenses for APS-C cameras.

Most FF 24-70mm lenses can also be used on APS-C cameras that share a mount with the FF counterparts in the same manufacturer's system. But with the smaller sensors found in APS-C cameras, a 24-70mm lens starts out in the *middle* of the normal range and gets longer from there. It gives the same view that a 36/38-105/112mm lens (1.5X such as Nikon, Sony, and Pentax/1.6X such as Canon) would give on a FF/35mm camera. Most photographers don't find that range near as useful without anything on the lower half of the normal range.

35-105mm or 40-115mm lenses have never been popular for 35mm film. 28-70mm or 28-80mm lenses were more common during the 35mm film era because they gave focal lengths from about 2/3 the measure of the diagonal of the 36x24mm 35mm film format to about 3/2 fo the same diagonal. (The 35mm name is derived from the width of the film strip, which allows 5.5mm on the top and bottom for the sprocket holes, leaving 24mm for the imaging area as measured perpendicular to the edge of the film. The actual name of the film size is an arbitrary "135.")

Answer (score 1):

Question is like "How long is a string"?

Focal length depends on scene considerations (i.e., wide angle or telephoto).  You use what is appropriate for the scene goal you want.

Focal length also depends on sensor size.

24 mm is more than moderately wide angle for a full frame sensor (35 mm film size),
but it is slightly telephoto for a 1.5 or 1.6 crop factor sensor,
and is stronger telephoto for a 5.5 crop compact.

Answer (score 0):

We mount lenses based on need. As we compose a picture, we select a lens that will best deliver the view we desire. If we mount a zoom lens, we can easily change the angle of view from wide-angle, thru normal, to telephoto. Your 24 thru 70 does just that. When set to minimum zoon, 24mm, this lens deliverers a moderately wide-angle view. When set to maximum, 70mm the view delivered is that of a moderate telephoto. When set to the center of its zoom range the view delivered is said to be “normal”. What that in mind, the 24mm thru 70mm zoom is suitable for most picture taking opportunities.

If your heart’s desire is sports or nature photography, you will need to invest in a longer lens, perhaps 200mm or 300mm to get you closer to the action. If you love landscape photography, most will advise a supper wised angle so you can enscope the vastness of a mountain range.

That being said, you might want to know, for a compact digital, 30mm is “normal and 20mm and shorter is the start the wide-angle angle. Telephoto is 60mm or longer. For portraiture, you should consider zooming in to 60 or 70mm.

The bottom line: a 24mm thru 70mm is a good choice for most picture taking opportunities.